# Is there a way to install docker command-line completion in a Docker for AWS CE deployment?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, docker

I've deployed the [CloudFormation Docker for AWS CE stack](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/#docker-community-edition-ce-for-aws), as per the instructions.

So far, though, I haven't been able install [Docker command-line completion](https://docs.docker.com/compose/completion/) on any node. Granted the OS in these is a special (apparently somewhat minified) OS, but it DOES have `/bin/bash` on it, so there *should* be a way to get autocomplete running, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is still true for 2021 on aws-linux2, giving you have installed the package `bash-completion`, here's my way to do it (despite the fact that the docker-completion should be in the docker-cli package, but doesn't work for me either):

```
sudo curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker-ce/master/components/cli/contrib/completion/bash/docker -o /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.sh
```

logout and login again (or just enter a new `bash`)